# Selenium not finding elements in HTML

Tags: html, django, selenium

I have an issue with selenium not finding elements in my HTML when I a testing. I have tried finding elements by id, name, and tag name. None of these methods work.

HTML:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body %}

<h2 id='id_foo'>{% for foo in foo_list%}
    #{{ foo.slug }}
{% endfor%}</h2>
<form method="POST" action='/'>
 <input  name='add_foos' placeholder='MORE FOOS!' id='id_add_foo'/>
 {% csrf_token %}
</form>


{% endblock %}
```

test, here is the bit of testing code that is not working. I have checked to see if it was checking the wrong page, and have confirmed that the test was working on the right HTML:

```
    foos = self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_foo')

    self.assertIn('dayofservice', foos.text)
```

Comment: Does it throw any errors? Are you on the correct page? Are there any iframes used on the page?

Comment: The only errors that it shows are that it cannot locate the element, I have checked if its on the correct page by printing the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shot in the dark, but you might just need to [give time the element to become present](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10)
foos = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'id_foo')))

self.assertIn('dayofservice', foos.text)
```

Comment: This happened to me as well, and then I read the docs. You can tell the driver to wait if the element is not found. This is the Java equivalent `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` which says, if you don't find it, wait 2 seconds. If you do, carry on as normal. This is useful when initialising your driver, because every hard-coded `wait` will force the test to stop whereas an implicit wait will only wait if an element isn't found.